# Restful HTTP API pattern

Tags: http, rest

I am designing a Restful HTTP API and have a design question.

In my application users should be able to suggest item creations.

Then I can either approve or disapprove them.

I wonder what the best VERB+URL pattern for this would be.

Example 1:

```
POST|GET|PUT|DELETE /items
```

A user POST a new item and I can either PUT it to "approved" from "pending" or DELETE it.

Here I must use GET /items?status=approved to get all approved items and GET /items?status=pending to get all pending items. Perhaps GET /items would get me all the approved ones by default.

But I don't get how I can prevent users from PUTting it to approved state.

or

Example 2:

```
POST|GET|PUT|DELETE /item_creation_suggestions
```

A user POST a new item suggestion and I can either approve by DELETE:ting it and do a POST /items or just DELETE it.

Here /items and /item_creation_suggestions are two separate collections. I just have to delete the suggestions and create the items when approving.

This makes it simple to protect my app from unauthorized access. I can just protect my /items with authorization, while /item_creation_suggestions could be used by anyone.

But this doesn't seem very Restful?

The same goes for when users are suggesting items updates and deletions and I either approve or disapprove them.

I am very new at Restful design so all feedback and suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one sounds good.

`POST /items` should create a new item and probably return a [`202 Accepted`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.3) status.
`GET /items` should return all approved items.
`GET /items?status=pending` should return pending items to users with the right permission.
`PUT /items/[id]` with a request body that designates a new status to change the status.
`DELETE /items/[id]` to delete the item.

In the end you need to decide what makes the most sense for *your* API, but the above sounds generally reasonable.

Comment: I don't think Accepted is appropriate here; It implies that the request was received, it appears valid upon first sight but this may change as the request gets processed in the background.

Comment: Yes, it depends on who the target audience is. From a user's perspective it makes sense that if I `POST` an item but it's not visible immediately, to receive a `202`. If there may also be an option to have an item published immediately and it's important to distinguish between the two, it's simple to do so using the HTTP status code.

Comment: Since 201 implies it is Created, 202 Accepted could imply the suggestion is accepted.

Comment: @user *202 Accepted - The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be  acted upon. [...] The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process [...] The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status [...]. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.2.3* Decide for yourself whether that fits your purpose. :)

Comment: Seems like it was designed specifically for my use case :)

Comment: Now the question is how do I make an UPDATE and DELETE suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I'd also strongly prefer the first setup.

> But I don't get how I can prevent users from PUTting it to approved state.

Your application logic needs to prevent users from POST'ing items with the approved state, if they don't have permission to do this. REST is not just a 'dead storage', you can actually process the request and throw a 403 Forbidden in case the user did something wrong.

Access control is still important and doesn't go against 'restfulness'.